# Login page did not give error massage if user give wrong details in magento 2 using with hyva theme

Tags: magento2, customer, login, error-message, hyva-themesmagento2-default-theme

I am using Magento 2 with a hyva Theme when I go to the login page and write the wrong credentials it will not give an error Massage like Please provide correct credentials in this page /customer/account/login/ can anyone guide me to do that
How to solve I didn't show an error message
And redirect to on the same page without any error
video link check ==> https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/19241045?key=6bbe82d68d414e53d9ae94f677a5f6aa

Here is my login.phtml code

```
<?php
/**
 * Hyvä Themes - https://hyva.io
 * Copyright © Hyvä Themes 2020-present. All rights reserved.
 * This product is licensed per Magento install
 * See https://hyva.io/license
 */
 
declare(strict_types=1);

use Hyva\Theme\Model\ViewModelRegistry;
use Hyva\Theme\ViewModel\Customer\LoginButton;
use Hyva\Theme\ViewModel\HeroiconsOutline;
use Hyva\Theme\ViewModel\HeroiconsSolid;
use Hyva\Theme\ViewModel\ReCaptcha;
use Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;

$heroiconsoutline = $viewModels->require(HeroiconsOutline::class);
$heroiconssolid = $viewModels->require(HeroiconsSolid::class);
$loginButtonViewModel = $viewModels->require(LoginButton::class);

// Do not replace this with $viewModels->require(ReCaptcha::class); that might break the dependency
// on the Magento_ReCaptchaCustomer module
$recaptcha = $block->getData('viewModelRecaptcha');
?>
<div class="w-full md:w-1/2 card mr-4">
    <div aria-labelledby="block-customer-login-heading">
        <form class="form form-login"
              action="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($block->getPostActionUrl()) ?>"
              method="post"
              x-data="initCustomerLoginForm()"
              @submit.prevent="submitForm()"
              id="customer-login-form">
            <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
            <fieldset class="fieldset login">
                <legend class="mb-3">
                    <h2 class="text-xl font-medium title-font text-primary">
                        <?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Login')) ?>
                    </h2>
                </legend>
                <div class="text-secondary-darker mb-8">
                    <?= $escaper->escapeHtml(
                        __('If you have an account, sign in with your email address.')
                    ) ?>
                </div>
                <div class="field email required">
                    <label class="label" for="email"><span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Email')) ?></span></label>
                    <div class="control">
                        <input name="login[username]"
                               class="form-input"
                               required
                               value="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getUsername()) ?>"
                            <?php if ($block->isAutocompleteDisabled()): ?>
                                autocomplete="off"
                            <?php endif; ?>
                               id="email"
                               type="email"
                               title="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Email')) ?>"/>
                               
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field password required">
                    <label for="pass" class="label"><span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Password')) ?></span></label>
                    <div class="control flex items-center">
                        <input name="login[password]"
                               class="form-input"
                               required
                               :type="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'"
                            <?php if ($block->isAutocompleteDisabled()): ?>
                                autocomplete="off"
                            <?php endif; ?>
                               id="pass"
                               title="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Password')) ?>"/>
                               
                        <div x-on:click="showPassword = !showPassword"
                             class="cursor-pointer px-4"
                             :aria-label="showPassword ? '<?= $escaper->escapeJs(__('Hide Password')) ?>' : '<?= $escaper->escapeJs(__('Show Password')) ?>'"
                        >
                            <template x-if="!showPassword">
                                <?= $heroiconssolid->eyeHtml('w-5 h-5'); ?>
                            </template>
                            <template x-if="showPassword">
                                <?= $heroiconssolid->eyeOffHtml('w-5 h-5'); ?>
                            </template>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?= $recaptcha ? $recaptcha->getInputHtml(ReCaptcha::RECAPTCHA_FORM_ID_CUSTOMER_LOGIN) : '' ?>
                <?= $block->getChildHtml('form_additional_info') ?>
                <div class="actions-toolbar flex justify-between pt-6 pb-2 items-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary disabled:opacity-75" name="send"
                            <?php if ($loginButtonViewModel->disabled()): ?> disabled="disabled" data-recaptcha-btn<?php endif; ?>
                        >
                            <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Sign In')) ?></span></button>
                        <a class="underline text-secondary" href="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl(
                            $block->getForgotPasswordUrl()
                        ) ?>"><span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Forgot Your Password?')) ?></span>
                        </a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <template x-if="displayErrorMessage">
                        <p class="text-red flex items-center">
                            <span class="inline-block w-8 h-8 mr-3">
                                <?= $heroiconsoutline->exclamationCircleHtml(); ?>
                            </span>
                            <template x-for="errorMessage in errorMessages">
                                <span x-html="errorMessage"></span>
                            </template>
                        </p>
                    </template>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="w-full">
        <?= $recaptcha ? $recaptcha->getLegalNoticeHtml(ReCaptcha::RECAPTCHA_FORM_ID_CUSTOMER_LOGIN) : '' ?>
    </div>
    <script>
        function initCustomerLoginForm() {
            return {
                errors: 0,
                hasCaptchaToken: 0,
                showPassword: false,
                displayErrorMessage: false,
                errorMessages: [],
                setErrorMessages(messages) {
                    this.errorMessages = [messages]
                    this.displayErrorMessage = this.errorMessages.length
                },
                submitForm() {
                    // do not rename $form, the variable is the expected name in the recaptcha output
                    const $form = document.querySelector('#customer-login-form');
                    <?= $recaptcha ? $recaptcha->getValidationJsHtml(ReCaptcha::RECAPTCHA_FORM_ID_CUSTOMER_LOGIN) : '' ?>

                    if (this.errors === 0) {
                        $form.submit();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

**Here is my message.phtml code**

```
<?php


declare(strict_types=1);

use Hyva\Theme\Model\ViewModelRegistry;
use Hyva\Theme\ViewModel\HeroiconsOutline;

$heroicons = $viewModels->require(HeroiconsOutline::class);

?>
<script>
    function initMessages() {
        "use strict";
        return {
            messages: window.mageMessages || [],
            isEmpty() {
                return this.messages.reduce(
                    function (isEmpty, message) {
                        return isEmpty && message === undefined
                    }, true
                )
            },
            removeMessage(messageIndex) {
                this.messages[messageIndex] = undefined;
            },
            addMessages(messages, hideAfter) {
                messages.map((message) => {
                    this.messages = this.messages.concat(message);
                    if (hideAfter) {
                        this.setHideTimeOut(this.messages.length -1, hideAfter);
                    }
                });
            },
            setHideTimeOut(messageIndex, hideAfter) {
                setTimeout((messageIndex) => {
                    this.removeMessage(messageIndex);
                }, hideAfter, messageIndex);
            },
            eventListeners: {
                ['@messages-loaded.window']() {
                    this.addMessages(event.detail.messages, event.detail.hideAfter)
                },
                ['@private-content-loaded.window'](event) {
                    const data = event.detail.data;
                    if (
                        data.messages &&
                        data.messages.messages &&
                        data.messages.messages.length
                    ) {
                        this.addMessages(data.messages.messages);
                    }
                },
                ['@clear-messages.window']() {
                    this.messages = [];
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<section id="messages"
         x-data="initMessages()"
         x-spread="eventListeners"
>
    <template x-if="!isEmpty()">
        <div class="w-full">
            <div role="alert" class="messages container mx-auto py-3">
                <template x-for="(message, index) in messages" :key="index">
                    <div>
                        <template x-if="message">
                            <div class="message" :class="message.type"
                                 :ui-id="'message-' + message.type"
                            >
                                <span x-html="message.text"></span>
                                <a href="#" class="close cursor-pointer" title="close"
                                   @click.prevent="removeMessage(index)">
                                    <?= $heroicons->xHtml('text-white', 18, 18); ?>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </template>
                    </div>
                </template>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
</section>
```

**Where we are wrong I don't know can anybody know how to solve this issue?**

Comment: Did you update the Hyva version? Which version of Hyva are you currently using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using alpinejs version 2, which is the default, then the problem is related to the way `hyva.initMessages` is triggered in cookies.phtml.

The event `alpine:initialized` is only available in alpine v3.

Override **Hyva_Theme::page/js/cookies.phtml** and change 
`window.addEventListener('alpine:initialized', hyva.initMessages);` 
to 
`window.addEventListener('load', hyva.initMessages);`

The same eventlistener is used in private-content.phtml 
Override **Hyva_Theme::page/js/private-content.phtml** and change
`window.addEventListener('alpine:initialized', loadSectionData);` 
to 
 `window.addEventListener('load', loadSectionData);`

Answer (score 0):

**We also face the same issue on our hyva theme upgrade.**

> **For Alpine.js version 3, you can update the files from your latest vendor directory.**

**Massage show Issue:**

```
vendor/hyva-themes/magento2-theme-module/src/view/frontend/templates/page/js/cookies.phtml
```

**Checkout Cart Issue:**

```
vendor/hyva-themes/magento2-theme-module/src/view/frontend/templates/page/js/private-content.phtml
```

> **For Alpine.js version 2, I have included the older version here.**

**app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/Hyva_Theme/templates/page/js/cookies.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Hyvä Themes - https://hyva.io
 * Copyright © Hyvä Themes 2020-present. All rights reserved.
 * This product is licensed per Magento install
 * See https://hyva.io/license
 */

declare(strict_types=1);

/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template $block */
?>
<script>
    'use strict';
    function dispatchMessages(messages, hideAfter) {
        const messagesEvent = new CustomEvent("messages-loaded", {
            detail: {
                messages: messages,
                hideAfter: hideAfter
            }
        });
        window.dispatchEvent(messagesEvent);
    }

<?php
    /**
     * The `hyva` JS namespace is being set by Hyva_Theme/src/view/frontend/templates/page/js/hyva.phtml
     * and should be included through Hyva_Theme/src/view/frontend/layout/default_hyva.xml
     */
?>
    if (typeof hyva === 'undefined' || (!hyva.getBrowserStorage || !hyva.getCookie || !hyva.setCookie)) {
        console.warn("Hyvä helpers are not loaded yet. Make sure they are included before this script");
    }

    (function( hyva, undefined ) {

        hyva.initFormKey = () => {
            const inputSelector = 'input[name="form_key"]',
                formKey = hyva.getFormKey();

            Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(inputSelector)).map(function (input) {
                input.value = formKey
            });
        }

        hyva.initMessages = () => {
            try {
                const messages = hyva.getCookie('mage-messages');
                window.mageMessages = messages ? JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(messages).replace(/\+/g, ' ')) : [];

                dispatchMessages(window.mageMessages);

                <?php
                /**
                 * In \Magento\Theme\Controller\Result\MessagePlugin::setCookie
                 * the cookie-domain is not set. Therefore, we need to skip it
                 * here as well.
                 */
                ?>
                // empty `mage-messages` cookie
                const skipSetDomain = true;
                hyva.setCookie('mage-messages','', -1, skipSetDomain);

            } catch (error) {
                console.warn('Error parsing Cookie Messages:', error);
            }
        }

        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', hyva.initFormKey);
        window.addEventListener('load', hyva.initMessages);


    }( window.hyva = window.hyva || {} ));
</script>
```

**app/design/frontend/VendorName/ModuleName/Hyva_Theme/templates/page/js/private-content.phtml**

```
<script>
    'use strict';
    {
        const private_content_key = 'mage-cache-storage';
        const private_content_expire_key = 'mage-cache-timeout';
        const private_content_version_key = 'private_content_version';
        const section_data_ids_key = 'section_data_ids';
        const mage_cache_session_id_key = 'mage-cache-sessid';
        const last_visited_store_key = 'last_visited_store';

        const ttl = 3600;

        if (typeof hyva === 'undefined' || (!hyva.getBrowserStorage || !hyva.getCookie || !hyva.setCookie)) {
            console.warn("Hyvä helpers are not loaded yet. Make sure they are included before this script");
        }

        function loadSectionData () {
            const browserStorage = hyva.getBrowserStorage();
            if (!browserStorage) {
                typeof window.dispatchMessages !== "undefined" && window.dispatchMessages(
                    [{
                        type: "warning",
                        text: "Please enable LocalStorage in your browser."
                    }]
                );
                return;
            }
            try {
                let isInvalid = false;

                if (hyva.getCookie(last_visited_store_key) !== CURRENT_STORE_CODE) {
                    isInvalid = true;
                }
                hyva.setCookie(last_visited_store_key, CURRENT_STORE_CODE, false, false);

                if (!hyva.getCookie(mage_cache_session_id_key)) {
                    isInvalid = true;
                    const skipSetDomain = true;
                    const days = false;
                    hyva.setCookie(mage_cache_session_id_key, true, days, skipSetDomain)
                }

                const cookieVersion = hyva.getCookie(private_content_version_key);
                const storageVersion = browserStorage.getItem(private_content_version_key);

                if (cookieVersion && !storageVersion || cookieVersion !== storageVersion) {
                    isInvalid = true;
                }

                const privateContentExpires = browserStorage.getItem(private_content_expire_key);
                if (privateContentExpires && new Date(privateContentExpires) < new Date()) {
                    browserStorage.removeItem(private_content_key);
                }

                if (isInvalid) {
                    fetchPrivateContent([]);
                } else if (cookieVersion && storageVersion && cookieVersion === storageVersion) {
                    const privateContent = JSON.parse(browserStorage.getItem(private_content_key));
                    if (
                        privateContent &&
                        privateContentExpires &&
                        privateContent.cart &&
                        privateContent.customer
                    ) {
                        dispatchPrivateContent(privateContent);
                    } else {
                        fetchPrivateContent([]);
                    }
                } else {
                    dispatchPrivateContent({});
                }

            } catch (error) {
                console.warn('Error retrieving Private Content:', error);
            }
        }

        window.addEventListener('load', loadSectionData);
        window.addEventListener('reload-customer-section-data', loadSectionData);

        function dispatchPrivateContent(data) {
            const privateContentEvent = new CustomEvent("private-content-loaded", {
                detail: {
                    data: data
                }
            });
            window.dispatchEvent(privateContentEvent);
        }

        function fetchPrivateContent(sections) {
            fetch(`${BASE_URL}customer/section/load/?sections=${encodeURIComponent(sections.join(','))}`, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
                }
            })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(
                    data => {
                        if (data) {
                            try {
                                const browserStorage = hyva.getBrowserStorage();

                                // merge new data preserving non-invalidated sections
                                const oldSectionData = JSON.parse(browserStorage.getItem(private_content_key) || '{}');

                                if ((! data.cart || ! data.cart.cartId) && oldSectionData['checkout-data']) {
                                    delete oldSectionData['checkout-data'];
                                }
                                const newSectionData = Object.assign(oldSectionData, data);

                                dispatchPrivateContent(newSectionData);

                                // don't persist messages, they've been dispatched already
                                if (newSectionData.messages && newSectionData.messages.messages ) {
                                    newSectionData.messages.messages = [];
                                }

                                browserStorage.setItem(private_content_key, JSON.stringify(newSectionData));

                                const expiresAt = new Date(Date.now() + (ttl * 1000)).toISOString();
                                browserStorage.setItem(private_content_expire_key, expiresAt);

                                const newCookieVersion = hyva.getCookie(private_content_version_key);
                                browserStorage.setItem(private_content_version_key, newCookieVersion);

                                // We don't need the section_data_ids in Hyvä, but we store them for compatibility
                                // with Luma Fallback. Otherwise, not all sections are loaded in Luma Checkout
                                hyva.setCookie(
                                    section_data_ids_key,
                                    JSON.stringify(
                                        Object.keys(data).reduce((sectionDataIds, sectionKey) => {
                                            sectionDataIds[sectionKey] = data[sectionKey]['data_id'];
                                            return sectionDataIds;
                                        }, {})
                                    ),
                                    false,
                                    true
                                );
                            } catch (error) {
                                console.warn("Couldn't store privateContent", error);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                );
        }
    }
</script>
```

> **You can check different below**

**private-content.phtml** -> https://www.diffchecker.com/8PhOKkvb/

**cookies.phtml** ->  https://www.diffchecker.com/xmXy1DDM/